# Writing hyperbolic inequalities as second order conic inequalities in GAMS

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gams-math

I coded a GAMS model that has hyperbolic inequalities and GAMS can solve it. However, when I transform the hyperbolic inequalities like`sqr(th(j)) =l= u(j)*f(j);` to second order conic inequalities as `2*th(j) =C= u(j) + f(j);` the solution returns error, saying that ***Cannot handle Cone = C = equations. Does any one has idea what is wrong here or if how I have to write the conic constraints?

This transformation is need so that I can use use Conic equations "=C=" to solve the model using MOSEK solver in GAMS.

Update: I changed my code a bit, and now it looks like this in a simplest form.

```
   i / 1*2 /
alias(i,j)
Parameters

            al(i)  /1 2
                  2 4/
            be(i) /1 1.5/;

Scalar D /500/;


Positive Variable  f(i), th(i), u(i), mu(i);
Variable obj;

Equation defobj, cons(i), conic1(j), conic2(j), conic3(j), demand;

defobj..  obj =e= sum(j,al(j)*be(j)*mu(j));
conic1(j).. 2*f(j) =C= th(j)+1;
conic2(j)..  2*th(j) =C= u(j)+f(j);
conic3(j)..  2*u(j)=C= mu(j)+f(j);
demand ..    sum(j, f(j))=e=D;

Model mod / defobj, conic2, conic1, conic3, demand /;
option qcp = MOSEK;
solve mod using nlp min obj;
```

Now GAMS gives me "Exit code=3".

Comment: Are you sure, that this comes from MOSEK? MOSEK is actually the solver which should be able to handle this. The message looks more like Conver or Decis output. Can you show more of your log?

Comment: @Lutz I updated my question and added my simplified code. Now getting a execution error.

Comment: Did you check the lst output? The error message are pretty specific: **** RHS for =C= has to be 0.0
     conic1(1)

**** RHS for =C= has to be 0.0
     conic1(2)

**** Variable enters more than one =C=  equation
     f(1)

**** Variable enters more than one =C=  equation
     f(2)

**** Variable enters more than one =C=  equation
     th(1)

**** Variable enters more than one =C=  equation
     th(2)

**** Variable enters more than one =C=  equation
     u(1)

**** Variable enters more than one =C=  equation
     u(2)

Comment: Sorry, format is not so nice here in the comment, but better you should see it better in the lst file

Comment: I did, but if i t does not help, it does not make sense if i do changes according to the message. The constraints should be as they need to be in my model. I feel like something is wrong with the way =C= constraints are written. But my knowledge of conic programming is limited. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I am also not an expert in this field. All I can suggest is to work on the reported errors (e.g., if I reduce the RHS of equation conic1 by 1, the first two errors go away) and to read more about it in the documentation, e.g. here: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_LanguageFeatures.html#UG_LanguageFeatures_ConicProgramming